# How to use different value in a column while using group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for butchering the question but i didn't know how to word it.

My question is if i have this as my result:

[Result http://puu.sh/cdKkz/5bf31b2172.png](http://puu.sh/cdKkz/5bf31b2172.png)

How would i be able to replace the manager_id with the managers name?

This is the employees table:

[image: employees table]

Comment: for starters, having manager_id <> 0 should be where manager_id <> 0.

Comment: Rather than post your answer in your question, you can answer your own question.  This keeps it in the Q&A format that people expect.

Comment: @paqogomez didnt know that, thanks ill do it now.

Comment: Your answer looks remarkably like @Srikanth's self join, perhaps just selecting his answer would be the best option.

Comment: Its also good form to upvote those that have helped you get to the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try a self join

```
select 
 e2.employee_id,
 e2.first_name, 
 e2.last_name,
  count(e1.employee_id) as employees
from
  employees e1
  inner join
  employees e2 ON e1.manger_id=e2.employee_id and e1.manager_id <> 0
 group by e2.employee_id,
 e2.first_name, 
 e2.last_name
```

Comment: Error: Column 'employees.EMPLOYEE_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' same thing i was getting when tring to just use First_name and last_name instead of manager_id in the select.

Comment: @Kevin It is good to have EMPLOYEE_ID in the select as two people might have the same first name and last name

Comment: @Kevin If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
select ie.first_name + ' ' + ie.last_name as 'manager_name', count(ie.employee_id) as 'employees'
from employees e inner join employees ie on e.manager_id = ie.employee_id
group by ie.first_name + ' ' + ie.last_name
```

Comment: Can you please explain how is the logic of this query different from mine all you did was add an  `alias` and `+`?